# Linux script to return domains on a web page

Tags: linux, bash

I was tasked with this question:
Write a bash script that takes a  URL as its first argument and prints out statistics of the number of links per host/domain in the HTML of the URL.

So for instance given a URL like www.bbc.co.uk it might print something like

```
www.bbc.co.uk: 45
bbc.com: 1
google.com: 2
Facebook.com: 4
```

That is, it should analyse the HTML of the page, pull out all the links, examine the href attribute, decide which links are to the same domain (figure that one out of course), and which are foreign, then produce statistics for the local ones and for the remote ones.

Rules: You may use any set of standard Linux commands in your script. You may not use any higher-level programming languages such as C or Python or Perl. You may however use awk, sed, etc.

I came up with the solution as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter a url eg www.bbc.com:"
read url
content=$(wget "$url" -q -O -)
echo "Enter file name to store URL output"
read file
echo $content > $file
echo "Enter file name to store filtered links:"
read links
found=$(cat $file | grep -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)"' | cut -d'"' -f2 | sort | uniq | awk '/http/' > $links)
output=$(egrep -o '^http://[^/]+/' $links | sort | uniq -c > out)
cat out
```

I was then told that "i must look at the data, and then check that your program deals satisfactorily with all the scenarios.This reports URLs but no the domains"
Is there someone out there that can help me or point me in the right direction so as i can be able to achieve my goal? what am i missing or what is the script not doing? I thought i had made it work as required.

Comment: How is C higher-level than shell script?

Comment: well its what the instructions said. I too dont see how. :)

Comment: You should avoid the large number of temporary files, or make sure you clean up afterwards.  Also, typically you would just normalize the input from the start, i.e. when you extract the `href`, trim it down to just the domain name before feeding it to `sort`.  A strong hint would be that if you use `awk` for anything, do as much as possible in `awk` and get rid of the `grep | cut | yada yada` chaff.

Comment: Keep in mind that other HTML tags call for content hosted in other domains, like `<img>`, `<script>`, `<iframe>` etc. I recommend you to track them too.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your script is:

```
      7 http://news.bbc.co.uk/
      1 http://newsvote.bbc.co.uk/
      1 http://purl.org/
      8 http://static.bbci.co.uk/
      1 http://www.bbcamerica.com/
     23 http://www.bbc.com/
    179 http://www.bbc.co.uk/
      1 http://www.bbcknowledge.com/
      1 http://www.browserchoice.eu/
```

I think they mean that it should look more like:

```
      7 news.bbc.co.uk
      1 newsvote.bbc.co.uk
      1 purl.org
      8 static.bbci.co.uk
      1 www.bbcamerica.com
     23 www.bbc.com
    179 www.bbc.co.uk
      1 www.bbcknowledge.com
      1 www.browserchoice.eu
```

Comment: ... or even total the results from news, newsvote, and www.bbc.co.uk into just a single number for `bbc.co.uk`; but in the general case, that is pretty hard to do (how do you know what the top-level domain name is in something like `www.in.c.a.aq` which I just made up?)

Comment: @tripleee yes this occurred to me as well, but the OP description doesn't define what the lecturer considers to be a domain.

Comment: ok yes it is hard to do but question is how to get it to do that. Michael first i would like my output to be like what u suggested in the second option. I can i get my code to do that? I have tried and its not an easy task to achieve